# Best OOP practise for a class returning list with class-objects?

Tags: c#, list, oop, class, methods

Maybe this is a subjective question.. but I've been trying to figure out what is the best way. 
Some example code:

```
class Banana
{
   private int _foo;

   public Banana()
   {
      _foo = 0;
   }
   public Banana(int whatever)
   {
      _foo = whatever;
   }

   public int Foo
   {
      ... get & set ... // get and set function
   }

   public list<Banana> MyFunction()
   {
      list myList<Banana> = new list<Banana>();

      for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
      {
         // This code?
         Banana banana = new Banana();
         banana.Foo = i;
         myList.Add(banana);

         // Or this?
         Foo = i;
         myList.Add(new Banana(Foo));
      }

      return myList;
   }
}
```

Does it matter? I think the later one looks cleaner, but requires a constructor that takes a value. 
Or is there a better way?
Thanks in advance! This is C# Code btw :)

Comment: Best for what? What criteria?

Comment: Why not myList.Add(new Banana(10)); then ?

Comment: Any criteria. Optimization (speed/memory).. or just best way to code

Comment: @GauthierG.Letellier > Well, works. But let's say Foo is a complex and much longer line. It would make it less readable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They don't do the same!**

```
// This code?
Banana banana = new Banana();
banana.Foo = 10;
myList.Add(banana);
```

Creates new `Banana` instance with `Foo = 10`, **does not affect current object at all**.

```
// Or this?
Foo = 10;
myList.Add(new Banana(Foo));
```

**Changes current object `Foo` property value to 10** and creates new `Banana` instance with the same value.

I am pretty sure you're looking for the first action.

There is also the third option:

```
myList.Add(new Banana(10));
```

**UPDATE**

Fourth version, using [Object Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) syntax:

```
Banana banana = new Banana() { Foo = 10 };
myList.Add(banana);
```

and Fifth

```
myList.Add(new Banana() { Foo = 10 });
```

Comment: Almost the same. The first example can have a constructor wich takes no arguments.

Comment: @Half_Baked you missed the point. The second version modifies the current instance, the first does not. That's not "almost the same".

Comment: @Half_Baked Looks like you still don't see the difference

Comment: @Filip. True. If adding 100 objects, in the first example i would need an array, otherwise it will be the same object 100 times in the list...

Comment: @Half_Baked No, that's not it. Difference is, the second version modifies current instance, when the first one doesn't.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek . They can be made to do the same, but I understand they do not work exactly the same

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek If I would like 100 different Bananas objects, the first example will add 100 bananas to the list with all value 10. So I would need an array. In the second example I dont. Was thinking one way was faster / better

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek True, but think of having a loop inside MyFunction, to create 100 objects with different values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28212/discussion-between-marcinjuraszek-and-half-baked)